# Input tensor ValueError when loading model BertClassifier Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, text-classification, bert-language-model, tensorflow2.x

--INTRO

I am training a BERT classifier using the google code from tf-models-official==2.3.0.
Everything works like charm: training, evaluating, saving checkpoints.

--THE PROBLEM

My problem arises when I save the **whole model** and then trying to reload it, I get this error.

I load my checkpoints

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = bert.bert_models.classifier_model(FLAGS_pretrained_bert["bert_config"], 2)[0]
    
    print(f"Loading the checkpoint in {PATH_ckpt}")
    model.load_weights(PATH_ckpt)
```

I save it as a whole model:

```
model.save("gs://MY_PATH")
```

Then reloading the model:

```
reloaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("gs://MY_PATH")
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Text>BertClassifier must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: None (missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: which library are you using ? Is it huggingface transformers ?

Comment: No, I am not! I am am using  the google package tf-models-official==2.3.0.